# Make compilation error

Tags: error

I have a running Alphanet node and I wanted to run a second mainnet node on the same machine. I cloned the tezos repository again, I changed to the current mainnet branch and 'make build-deps' was executed without errors. However, I get the following compilation error while trying to compile the current code (using 'make') in the mainnet branch:

[image]

I don't understand the reason of the error and how I can fix it.

Comment: Are you able to build successfully from the first clone or not ?

Comment: If you mean the one for the alphanet, then yes.

Comment: Ok so your issue is about building current version of mainnet, not about simply rebuilding a second time the same repo. Can you please privide the commit hash of the HEAD you see

Comment: Exactely, I can compile the current version of Alphanet without problems, but not the current version of Mainnet. HEAD commit hash: eb3476228524d94267b355951cececf3ea50300f

Comment: EAGAIN in this case probably means you're out of disk space. What does `df -h /` show?

Comment: 293 GB available

Comment: Ah right, it says `launch_thread` so how much memory do you have available? `free -h`

Comment: I still do not understand the reason of the error, but after stopping the running alphanet node, I recompiled the mainnet code and it worked without problems.

Comment: Maybe it is the memory issue?

Comment: BTW: if you found the answer you can post and accept it by yourself in order not to leave an open question.